# How to share structures (content types) across multiple sites?

Tags: nodes, features, subsites

**Info:**
I have DRUPAL6.26 with subdomains all install in a single database. Each site has a prefix for its tables.

**My situation:**
I have shared users between subdomains by sharing the {users},{sessions},{profile} tables in settings.php.

**My questions:**

- How can I share structures (Content types in my case) only across multiple sites/subdomains without their original content ?
- Can I use it for content types by sharing the table: node_type and all CCK FIELDS tables.
  Or could there be another way to achieve this ?

Comment: Is this something that you'd do only once? If yes, then Features probably would be the standard answer.

Comment: @KariKääriäinen No, Things like content types, meta tag and post settings, taxonomy. the structure of pages under site building, site configuration, user permissions. All the things that make a site consistent in its look and function needs to be shared between main site and subdomains. so once I make changes in MAIN site the changes need to be applied on all subdomains as well.do you think the features module can take care of this too?

Comment: That's a lot more than content types. You might want to edit your question. What you're aiming at sounds like an administrating and upgrading nightmare. Check out the Organic groups module. Could be easier creating restricted sets of users and contents with that.